# NHibernate and Auto Incremented ID Deadlocks

Tags: nhibernate

I've been using SharpArchitecture with NHibernate to build my site which can have many users.  My tables are setup with Primary Keys in the database setup as IDENTITY(1,1).  The last couple of days I've been noticing a bunch of deadlock problems occurring based on the log file as such:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 55) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

And I get this error sometimes which may be related:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

In my web.config I've included this line to set the db isolation property:

```
<property name="connection.isolation">ReadUncommitted</property>
```

Based on what I've found through my searches is that the auto incremented ID is locking the table, even though I have ReadUncommitted.  That being said:

- Am I correct with this conclusion?
- If so, I assume if I go with generating the ID with something like HiLo or GuidComb it would solve the issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- probably yes
- yes

with many users HiLo is also reduces traffic and load on the database so switching to it would be good anyway.